# Difference between global define and global variable declaration

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand the mix use of pointer and array in an array declaration. The usage of the global variable declaration and define directive makes me a little confused. The code snippet is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int ts1[2] = {(1), (2)};
const int ts2[2] = {(2), (3)};
const int ts3[2] = {(3), (4)};
const int ts4[2] = {(4), (5)};
#define tc1 {1,2}
#define tc2 {2,3}
#define tc3 {3,4}
#define tc4 {4,5}

int main()
{
    const int arr1[][2][2] = {{{(1), (2)}, {(2), (3)}}, {{(3), (4)}, {(4), (5)}}};
    const int *arr2[2][2] = {{ts1, ts2}, {ts3, ts4}};
    const int arr3[][2][2] = {{tc1, tc2}, {tc3, tc4}};
    const int *arr4[2][2] = {{tc1, tc2}, {tc3, tc4}};

    printf("%d\n", arr2[1][1][1]);
    printf("%d\n", arr3[1][0][1]);
    printf("%d\n", arr4[1][0][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

arr1 is a normal way of declaring an array.
arr2 w/ global var decl and arr3 w/ define directive works fine as well. However, arr4 w/ define directive issues me a seg fault while running. Considering define directive simply replace whatever it defines into arr4's intialized list, why arr2 can work but arr4 can not?

Comment: what compiler do you use? gcc with no special flag already gives a lot of warnings...

Comment: If you aren't sure what effect a `#define` has, you can often use your code editor's Search and Replace feature to achieve the same effect. It requires you to be smart if it's a define that takes parameters, but you can replace all `tc1` with `{1,2}` and the code will compile _exactly_ the same (assuming you remove the line that defined `tc1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying the macro substitution, this:

```
const int *arr4[2][2] = {{tc1, tc2}, {tc3, tc4}};
```

Becomes:

```
const int *arr4[2][2] = {{{1,2}, {2,3}}, {{3,4}, {4,5}}};
```

`arr4` is a 2D array of `int *`, but you assign something like `{1,2}` to each element which is not a `int *`.  This *could* work if you use a compound literal:

```
const int *arr4[2][2] = {{(int [])tc1, (int [])tc2}, {(int [])tc3, (int [])tc4}};
```

Which becomes:

```
const int *arr4[2][2] = {{(int []){1,2}, (int []){2,3}}, {(int []){3,4}, (int []){4,5}}};
```

Then you assign an actual array, which decays into a pointer to its first element, to each element of `arr4`.

This works:

```
const int *arr2[2][2] = {{ts1, ts2}, {ts3, ts4}};
```

Because `ts1`, `ts2`, `ts3`, and `ts4` are arrays of type `int`, so using them here results in them decaying to a pointer to their first elements.

Comment: I see. So the compiler can not automatically treat string initializer {1,2} as an array, and arrange/allocate space for it.